# solr multivalued dynamic field index doesn't have multiple values

Tags: solr, wcs

I have following field defined as dynamic and multivalued but noticed that index only has last string for the document/sku, as opposed to multiple values for this field.
Am I missing anything here since I don't see any other fields of this type in our current WebSphere Commerce(WCS) SOLR set up that uses SOLR .4.10.3?

I only seee below data in SOLR index instead of all the data getting repeated for each 'category_' id before colon character.

```
<arr name="category_6677160">
 <str>Food Prep Items</str>
</arr>
```

schema entry:

```
<dynamicField name="category_*" type="wc_text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

x-data-config.xml entry:

```
<field column="CATEGORYDATA"  clob="true"/>
```

Added below entries to solrcore.properties to use the new table during data import process:

```
dataImporter.ext.querySelect=TI_CATCATEGORYDATA.CATEGORYDATA CATEGORYDATA,
dataImporter.ext.queryFrom=LLEFT OUTER JOIN TI_CATCATEGORYDATA_0_1 
TI_CATCATEGORYDATA ON (CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID=TI_CATCATEGORYDATA.CATENTRY_ID)
```

Test CATEGORYDATA data for one of the SKU in custom TI_ table based on SQL used in wc-dataimport-preprocess-catcategories.xml. I don't see any issue with this file or the data since data looks as expected and below is sample data for one of the CATENTRY_Id(SKU) records.

```
category_344657629:Kitchen Prep;
category_76902:Fry and Taco Baskets;
category_3074676935:Frying Supplies;
category_30744594:Fry Baskets;
category_306677009:Taco Stuff;
category_30457345616677030:Fryer;
category_30757345616677070:Fry Baskets & Accessories;
category_3457345616677089:Food Preparation Items||category_677089:Fry 
 Baskets;
category_74457345616677104:Misc Venues;
category_3074457345616677112:Tableware;
category_616677158:Miscellaneous Smallwares;
category_457345616677160:Fry Baskets and 
 Accessories||category_6677160:Food Prep Items
```

Comment: Mapping these items probably require more than what you've shown - please add your complete import configuration.

Comment: updated solrcore.properties information as well since it will be used during data import process, no changes were made other than above to add new field to the index.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with processor entry in dataimport-preprocess-catcategories.xml file?
The data is in above mentioned format when I used com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.StaticAttributeDataPreProcessor' and get NPE when tried to use com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DynamicMultiValueDataPreProcessor. There is nothing in the pre-process log even with full tracing enabled.

`<_config:data-processing-config processor="com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DynamicMultiValueDataPreProcessor" masterCatalogId="100024" fetchSize="500" batchSize="500">`

Comment: That sounds plausible. There is [a Log transformer that you can add](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LogTransformer) to log anything before and after the processor in your dih config.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was an issue with group by clause in the SQL used in dataimport-preprocess-catcategories.xml. There was no need for additional group clause since SOLR will automatically group the data based on catalog id in indexed data.